# While displaying Complete database in jupyter notebook instead it shows few starting and ending rows

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

While displaying Complete database in jupyter notebook instead it shows few starting and few ending rows I tried setting set.maxrows but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a pandas DataFrame. Then you can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
display(<your data frame>)
```